# terminating connection due to conflict with recovery, user was holding a relation lock for too long

Tags: postgresql

I am getting below error on my PostgreSQL slave node:

```
FATAL: terminating connection due to conflict with recovery
DETAIL: User was holding a relation lock for too long.
```

Parameters enabled: `hot_standby_feedback = on`

When I query the `pg_stat_database_conflicts` view, I only get the count of conflicts that happened till now. Is there any way to find that which query is holding lock (either on master or slave node)?

Comment: Can you look into the PostgreSQL log if there is more information? It must be one of the tables that you have used in your current transaction. You can use the `pg_stat_replication` view on the primary to find out where replication currently is and examine the transaction log with `pg_waldump` for the `LOCK` record.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any another way to find out query because this error comes within fraction of seconds and till the time we try to find out root cause, system is back to normal.

Comment: But you know what statement was running on the standby that got the error, right? Start investigating there.